# Got error 66 "Object is remote" from storage engine InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am running `ALTER TABLE article_attachment CHANGE  content  content LONGBLOB NULL`

on this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `article_attachment` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `article_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `filename` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
 `content_size` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `content_type` text,
 `content_id` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
 `content_alternative` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `content` longblob NOT NULL,
 `create_time` datetime NOT NULL,
 `create_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `change_time` datetime NOT NULL,
 `change_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `disposition` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `article_attachment_article_id` (`article_id`),
 KEY `FK_article_attachment_create_by_id` (`create_by`),
 KEY `FK_article_attachment_change_by_id` (`change_by`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34672 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And get the error

`Got error 66 "Object is remote" from storage engine InnoDB`

Google returns almost nothing regarding the error.

I did increase `max_allowed_packet` to 999999488 but that did not help.

*Update*

I tried to change another column in the same table an there it tells me `The size of BLOB/TEXT data inserted in one transaction is greater than 10% of redo log size. Increase the redo log size using innodb_log_file_size.`

Maybe this is related...

Comment: In case someone sends an attachment that hits some other limit (after this one is fixed), perhaps you should consider storing attachments as separate files.  `article_attachment` could be changed to have the file name instead of the `longblob`.

Comment: @RickJames I would, but https://www.otrs.com/ does not ;)

Comment: `LONGBLOB` is limited to 4GB. `max_allowed_packet` may be limited to 16MB.  Other pieces of the stack (webserver, etc) also have limits.  So you may be stuck with aborting somewhere.  Can you catch the max before you hit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I followed https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1265/42097 and increased `innodb_log_file_size` in my.cnf mysqld section.

Mysql ANALYSE of the table told me article_attachment.content max_length is 22942326. So I set innodb_log_file_size to 300000000.

Now ALTER TABLE worked.